# How to add UI components on specific coordinates

Tags: android

I have to create a UI with components(TextView, Bottons etc) placed at particular coordinates as specified in an XML coming from a server. I am currently using AbsoluteLayout but since its deprecated i want to use some other method.

Answer (score 1):

Use FrameLayout, this way you can position x/y exact anywhere using the margin (i.e. marginTop, marginLeft) properties of the components.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html). There you can set the exact coordinates of the UI element. However, I would no really recommend to use in any situation, because you can get in trouble with different screen size/resolution.

Comment: Its a server requirment. Server will send the coordinates itself as the UI is required to be fully dynamic

Comment: also Absolute layout is deprecated so it's not recommended to use